# What's the purpose of a repository having both an ID and name?

Tags: maven

When looking at the [documentation for setting up additional repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) for Maven, I came across the following example:

```
<project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo2</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
</project>
```

What advantages are gained from having both an `id` and a `name` for every repository? Are these referenced by other Maven commands?

The [settings documentation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-settings/settings.html#repository) specifies that `id` is "a unique identifier for a repository" and `name` is a "human readable name of the repository" but this does not give any insights into why `id` is needed.

Comment: The id is used to make authentication via the entries in `settings.xml` which references the `id` (see server section).

Comment: I think ID is the "important thing" which is used everywhere to reference repositories, while name would better read as "description". But this is just a hunch.